# Jquery get <p> html and replace with text box

Tags: jquery

I have a link, when I click on it, it should select a div p tag contents and replace the p tag with text box and previously stored contents.

Now my code is removing the p tag and adding text box but it is removing text box immediately and inserting p tag. After user presses enter, I want ajax fn to be called.

This is what I tried,

```
<a href="" id="den">DEN</a>
<div id="test">
<p id="x">I am doing good</p>
</div>
 $("#den").live("click", function () {
       var con = $("#test >p#x").html();
       $("#test > p#x").remove();
       $("#test > p#x").append('<textarea type="text" value='+con+'></textarea>');

}); 
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not make changes in removed element   [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2rwMY/)

Note . textarea does not have type attribute

and  . Setting value of textarea would not show in box

```
<a href="" id="den">DEN</a>
<div id="test">
<p id="x">I am doing good</p>
</div>
 $("#den").on("click", function () {
   $("#test > p#x").html('<textarea >' +  $("#test >p#x").html() +'</textarea>');
 return false;
```

});

Comment: :Did you test this code ?

Comment: No, but I tested how textarea work

Comment: :can you show me the working code ?

Comment: I added working jsfidle link

Comment: :It worked, now when I enter, how do I call ajax fn.

Comment: :But why return false at the end.

Comment: You can bind you button. on button click call a jquery AJAX with required parameters http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @ram to prevent default behaviour of anchor(a) tag

Comment: 2 overkills here : First, `$("#test > p#x")` is called twice. For optimisation, you should put it in a variable. `var px = $("#test > p#x"); px.html(...)`. Second, as id should be unique, `$("#test > p#x");` should be `$("#x");`. Finally, you should have : `var px = $("#x"); px.html(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

After you remove `#x`, it's not in the DOM, so appending to it useless. If you want to replace the element's contents, use `.html()` instead. Also, [`<textarea>`s have text content, not `value` attributes.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-textarea-element)

```
$("#den").live("click", function () {
    var con = $("#test >p#x").html();
    $("#test > p#x").html('<textarea type="text">'+con+'</textarea>');
});
```

Note, since element IDs must be unique, the selector `#test > p#x` is grossly overspecified, and is equivalent to simply `#x`. There's also a [simpler, idiomatic way](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to accomplish this entire task:

```
$("#den").live("click", function () {
    $("#x").html(function (i, oldHtml) {
        return '<textarea type="text">'+oldHtml+'</textarea>';
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/PSV7A/